# Is it possible to use php in an Amazon S3 website? Perhaps another template system that works with S3?

Tags: php, templates, amazon-s3, smarty

I currently have a handful of static pages being hosted with the new Amazon S3 Website feature.

However, I'm going to start adding a few more pages soon and would love the ability for a basic template system for a header and footer with something such as smarty or even stacey cms.

I don't need a database just want to have the convenience of a template system. Any idea if I can do this with PHP in S3? If not, is there another way to get this to work in S3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. It's storage, not a full web server environment.

Comment: I'd like to do this as well. Have you had any luck hosting a .php page on S3 Slythic?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.

I hoped that I could use php language on Amazon S3, however I don't think we can use PHP on S3.

It says that Static Website Hosting, which means it will run only static files such as html, js, jpg, and other static files.

If you want to use php, I think you should run Linux that operate php language.